# Appending to List Eror

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm new to Python and am struggling with the syntax to join a new value to a list and then add that to a list of lists. `loc_ref` and `from_loc` are both pre-existing lists and `user_says` is a user input field using `user_says = input("Enter Data")`

```
print(loc_ref,"\n")  #returns [['COMPANY|ADDRESS|CITY|STATE|LOCATION']] 
print(from_loc,"\n") #returns ['COMPANY A', '1515 STREET RD', 'CITYA', 'ST'] 
print([user_says])
loc_ref = loc_ref.append(from_loc + [user_says]) 
print(loc_ref)  #returns None
```

Why is `loc_ref` returning `None` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the value of `loc_ref` to `None`

`loc_ref = loc_ref.append(from_loc + [user_says])`

`list.append` does not return the list with the appended value, it returns `None`, as a result, `loc_ref` is set to None

Try just:
`loc_ref.append(from_loc + [user_says])` and get rid of the `loc_ref =`

Answer (score 2):

That is because the method `append` returns `None`. Sounds weird? That's because it works `in-place` and changes the list `loc_ref`, but will always return `None`.

All you have to do is simply change your line to:

```py
loc_ref.append(from_loc + [user_says])
```

The original list will simply have the appended value in it, at the last position.

Read more about it [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append):

> The append() method adds a single item to the existing list. It **doesn't return a new list**; rather it modifies the original list.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append

> As mentioned, the append() method only modifies the original list. It doesn't return any value.

append() is  a method that doesn't return anything just doing  `loc_ref.append(from_loc + [user_says])` will be enough